# Wheel behaviour for HTC Desire (setting alarm)

Tags: htc-desire, alarm, user-interface

A couple of days ago I was setting my alarm on my HTC Desire (rooted and flashed with InsertCoin) when I realised a really cool behaviour with the wheel whilst selecting the 'minutes'.

Basically, no matter how quickly I flicked it would stop at 00,15,30,45. ie. it would be scrolling fairly fast, but would jolt to a halt and stop at '15'

Now, I didn't really think about it that much, other than "wow this is cool, don't remember this before"

However, now I can't seem to reproduce the same behaviour - when I flick the wheel it just scrolls and eventually slows to a halt at any old number...

Just wondering, did I somehow do something special to trigger the "smart scroll"? Has anyone else seen similar behaviour with the scrolling wheel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On my Desire with InsertCoin 1.1.0 (CM7 + Sense) the "smart scroll" feature is only active on the scroller for specifying the appointment time in the calendar.

Comment: Ah yes, I think you are correct! I must've been adding a new calendar event and not setting my alarm. Thanks for pointing it out :) (though I do wish this "smart scroll" behaviour was everywhere when setting time)